# Is the GET request containing the code parameter vulnerable in OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: security, web-applications, oauth-2.0

I'm currently assessing the security of an application using Oauth2 authentication.
During the Oauth dance, when authenticating with user John Doe in browser A, one of the requests is:
GET https://siteImAssessing.cxx/?code=LongOAUTH2AuthorizationCode

What I've noticed is that I can copy and paste that request in a different browser (browser B) and I become John Doe in that browser as well without the need to enter John Doe's credentials. (I receive fresh JWT tokens in browser B as well)

Would this be considered normal Oauth2 behavior?

- The value of code expires after 5 minutes and when the user refreshes the browser window in either browser A or B.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not be able to be John Doe in both browsers. The authorization code can only be used once (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-27). The code should be invalidated after it is used to get a token.

If you can copy the request and successfully execute it from another browser (session), it means the authorization server is not invalidating the code after it was used. You may want to file a bug with the vendor of the authorization server.